# So that is it a error on gathering sources and javadocs in maven =D and someone guess some clue about how to handle it?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

So that is it a error on gathering sources and javadocs in maven =D and someone guess some clue about how to handle it?
Also try in google but did not found something usefull for: [ERROR] "Could not" "download sources" for "org.apache.tomcat" tomcat-servlet-api 7.0.0.

my pom project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.beingjavaguys.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringRestCrud</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringRestCrud Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <org.apache.tomcat.version>7.0.0</org.apache.tomcat.version>
        <context.path>SpringRestCrud</context.path>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>${pom.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- H2 in-memory database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.145</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF 2 API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0-m07</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

log from maven:

```
01/12/16 08:00:21 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:00:21 BRST: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
01/12/16 08:00:21 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:00:21 BRST: [INFO] Copying 2 resources
01/12/16 08:00:21 BRST: [INFO] Changed resources require a complete clean of filtered resources of SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:00:21 BRST: [INFO] Executing resource filtering for SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:00:21 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:00:54 BRST: [INFO] C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:00:54 BRST: [INFO]  mvn -B clean
01/12/16 08:01:03 BRST: [INFO] C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:01:03 BRST: [INFO]  mvn -B install
01/12/16 08:08:25 BRST: [INFO] Using org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WarLifecycleMapping lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.beingjavaguys.sample:SpringRestCrud:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\pom.xml.
01/12/16 08:08:26 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.0/tomcat-juli-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:27 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.0/tomcat-juli-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:27 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/7.0.0/tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:27 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/7.0.0/tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:27 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/7.0.0/tomcat-api-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:27 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/7.0.0/tomcat-api-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:27 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/7.0.0/tomcat-util-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:28 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/7.0.0/tomcat-util-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:28 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.0/tomcat-juli-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:28 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.0/tomcat-juli-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:28 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/7.0.0/tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:29 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/7.0.0/tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:29 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/7.0.0/tomcat-api-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:29 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/7.0.0/tomcat-api-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:29 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/7.0.0/tomcat-util-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:29 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/7.0.0/tomcat-util-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:31 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api//tomcat-servlet-api-.pom
01/12/16 08:08:31 BRST: [WARN] The POM for org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar: is missing, no dependency information available
01/12/16 08:08:31 BRST: [INFO] Cleaning filtered folder for SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:08:32 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:08:32 BRST: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
01/12/16 08:08:32 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:08:32 BRST: [INFO] Copying 2 resources
01/12/16 08:08:32 BRST: [INFO] Changed resources require a complete clean of filtered resources of SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:08:32 BRST: [INFO] Executing resource filtering for SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:08:32 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:08:49 BRST: [INFO] Using org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WarLifecycleMapping lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.beingjavaguys.sample:SpringRestCrud:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\pom.xml.
01/12/16 08:08:50 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.0/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:50 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.0/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.0.pom
01/12/16 08:08:50 BRST: [INFO] Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.0/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:51 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.0/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.0.jar
01/12/16 08:08:51 BRST: [INFO] Cleaning filtered folder for SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:08:52 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:08:52 BRST: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
01/12/16 08:08:52 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:08:52 BRST: [INFO] Copying 2 resources
01/12/16 08:08:52 BRST: [INFO] Changed resources require a complete clean of filtered resources of SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:08:52 BRST: [INFO] Executing resource filtering for SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:08:52 BRST: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
01/12/16 08:08:59 BRST: [INFO] Update started
01/12/16 08:09:00 BRST: [INFO] Using org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WarLifecycleMapping lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.beingjavaguys.sample:SpringRestCrud:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\pom.xml.
01/12/16 08:09:00 BRST: [INFO] Adding source folder /SpringRestCrud/src/main/java
01/12/16 08:09:00 BRST: [INFO] Adding resource folder /SpringRestCrud/src/main/resources
01/12/16 08:09:00 BRST: [INFO] Adding source folder /SpringRestCrud/src/test/java
01/12/16 08:09:00 BRST: [INFO] Adding resource folder /SpringRestCrud/src/test/resources
01/12/16 08:09:01 BRST: [INFO] Cleaning filtered folder for SpringRestCrud
01/12/16 08:09:01 BRST: [INFO] Update completed: 1 sec
01/12/16 08:09:10 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.0/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.0-javadoc.jar
01/12/16 08:09:10 BRST: [ERROR] Could not download sources for org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:7.0.0
01/12/16 08:09:10 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.0/tomcat-juli-7.0.0-javadoc.jar
01/12/16 08:09:10 BRST: [ERROR] Could not download sources for org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.0
01/12/16 08:09:11 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/7.0.0/tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.0-javadoc.jar
01/12/16 08:09:11 BRST: [ERROR] Could not download sources for org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:7.0.0
01/12/16 08:09:12 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/7.0.0/tomcat-api-7.0.0-javadoc.jar
01/12/16 08:09:12 BRST: [ERROR] Could not download sources for org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-api:7.0.0
01/12/16 08:09:12 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/7.0.0/tomcat-util-7.0.0-javadoc.jar
01/12/16 08:09:12 BRST: [ERROR] Could not download sources for org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util:7.0.0
01/12/16 08:09:12 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for log4j:log4j:1.2.17
01/12/16 08:09:12 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.7.4
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.4
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.4
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.7.4
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.5.RELEASE
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for com.h2database:h2:1.2.145
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for junit:junit:4.12
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for org.primefaces:primefaces:6.0
01/12/16 08:09:13 BRST: [INFO] Downloaded javadoc for com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.2.0-m07
```

Comment: Simply ignore it. I think this files are not in the maven repository

Comment: The sources for tomcat-servlet-api are in Maven central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.0/ ...You can not find the javadoc for this package...